# Bootstrapper.BackRequested event is not firing

Tags: uwp, template10

In my Template 10 based UWP app, I am trying to override the default `BackButton` behavior. In a tertiary page, I would like to customize the behavior to go back to the primary home page.

I have wired up that event, but my handler is never fired.

The XAML:

```
<controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" BackButtonVisibility="Visible" BackButtonContent="Home" Frame="{x:Bind Frame}"
                     RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
```

The ViewModel events (relevant code only):

```
    public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state) {
        App.BackRequested += HandleGoBack;
    }

    public override async Task OnNavigatedFromAsync(IDictionary<string, object> state, bool suspending) {
        App.BackRequested -= HandleGoBack;
    }

    void HandleGoBack(object sender, Template10.Common.HandledEventArgs e) {
            while ( NavigationService.CanGoBack )
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

The Navigation events are firing, but the `BackRequested` event is not firing.

What am I missing?

Comment: I made a basic demo from your codes but failed reproducing your problem. Could you please share a basic demo through online Repository?

Comment: It won't repro outside of my project, so something else must be interfering. Thanks for checking.